# Disable case sensitive copy / paste in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, copy-paste

If I copy text from Chrome it copies the CSS `text-transform` property along with it... which I find very annoying.

I understand that if a word is actually set in capitals, then the browser will have to paste it like that. However, if a word is only set in capitals because it is styled like that with CSS, then I would prefer that it ignored it.

So basically I'd prefer the copy / paste functionality of Firefox but in Chrome.

Comment: Seems like this is a current bug in WebKit browsers: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43202